# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";"

Tags: database, plsql, error-handling

i tried to write code on online oracle compiler and in code i used to get value from keyboard as num:=# but it show error , could any help me what will be solution could be.

---

```
declare 
num number(3);
begin 
num:= &num;
for i in 1..10 loop
dbms_output.put_line('number is: ' || num);
end loop;
end;
/
set serveroutput on;
/
```

---

Comment: You have six semicolons. Doesn't your compiler report the line number?

Comment: Set server output is a SQLPlus command NOT sql nor plsql. Therefore not semi-colon terminated. And to be useful it must come before the script that needs it. What happened here is your anonymous block ran successfully, because server output was not on, you did not see the results. Then errored on setting it.

Comment: What is "online oracle compiler"? Are you sure it handles `&num`? That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

In an online Oracle compiler or SQLPlus, you can't directly prompt the user for input using the & substitution variable as you would in SQLPlus or SQL Developer.

However, you can achieve a similar effect by using the ACCEPT command. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to accept input from the user:

DECLARE
num datatype (3)
BEGIN
ACCEPT num PROMPT 'Enter a number: '

FOR var IN (1 to 10) LOOP
('Number is: ' || num)
END of loop
END
/
datatype = NUMBER
end statements with semi colon

In this code, the `ACCEPT` command prompts the user to enter a number, and the value entered by the user is stored in the `num` variable. The loop then executes 10 times, and the value of `num` is displayed using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.

Make sure to enable the server output using the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` command to see the output of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.